# Laravel Menu Builder for users

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, menu

I'm looking for a way to give users a possibility to build their own page, including a menu. Therefore, I want to give them the possibility to do it graphically, so they can add a menu item, can see a little preview how it's looking. The menu then has to be saved in the db under the relating user id.

How can I implement such a functionality or how can I search for tutorials? Didn't find anything that is what I need.

I'm using Laravel 5.3, maybe this could help making it easier, and jQuery is also possible.

I have not been able to post code, because I have no code for this yet. I have no idea how to get started with this "graphical live building".

Comment: You might need to take a look at Jquery drag and drop functionality. So you can have list of menus one side, then user can drag to the other side as a preview

Comment: @Michel Could the user then simply add items, sort them, and do I have a chance to save them into the db then?

Comment: @Michel relating to jquery droppable I found this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/MvnEv/), where you can add items, you know if there are also functionalities to edit items after added, delete them, etc..?

Comment: Check my answer below. That will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    //So you have what user sent here as "**data**" You can use that to make an AJX call
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Remember JQuery drag and drop required.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle so I can see what it does and how it works? And what jQuery drag and drop do you mean exactly? and can I change menu items in your example as well?